# check condition again and again until it would be true

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add my `recursioN` func check in my code before execution some code. That check repeat again and again until it would be true. And when condition will be true then it goes on next line and execute my further code.  I did't want use while loop. I am using `seder.tag` in my `audioControlButtonAction` so due to this reason i cannot add my all code in another function that call when `Internet connection OK`. Anyone have any idea how i can do this. 
Thanks

```
func audioControlButtonAction(sender: UIButton){
// Here i want to add an Internet Reachability it repeats until it gets true

// Execute my code after condition will be true

}

    func recursioN(){

            if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
                print("Internet connection OK")
            } else {
                showAlert()
                print("Internet connection FAILED")
            }
        }

        func showAlert(){
            let createAccountErrorAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()

            createAccountErrorAlert.delegate = self

            createAccountErrorAlert.title = "No Internet Connection"
            createAccountErrorAlert.message = "Make sure your device is connected to the internet."
            createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss")
            createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Retry")

            createAccountErrorAlert.show()
        }

        func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){

            switch buttonIndex{

            case 1:
                recursioN()
                NSLog("Retry")
                break;
            case 0:
                NSLog("Dismiss");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog("Default");
                break;
                //Some code here..

            }
        }
```

Comment: i think that checking if the internet is UP with recursion is stupid, perhaps you dont know what recursion it is at all... I would rather create timer that check it every three seconds - if internet is available do the Function that you want and stop timer... with recursion you will create thousands of the same functions in second and all of them will return false...

Comment: This isn't the right way to do things. If the audio button can't function when you have no internet connectivity then disable the button when you have no connectivity. Use a callback from reachability to enable the buttons when you have connectivity.  You should also "grey" the buttons to show that they are disabled and provide feedback to the user

Comment: use network reachability from GitHub

Comment: Mazel Tov, I know about recursion, sorry for my function name it is not actually do same that `recursion` mean. If you check again my function it will not create thousands of the same function in seconds because it just call when user tap on retry button after first first execution, if user tap on Dismiss button then it goes out from alertView. I am using this method in my another code and it perfectly works. I did want use timer. i just want to force user to on internet when it press on play button. Have you any idea what i can do whiteout timer??

Comment: Paulw11. Thanks. But i just want force to user for connect to internet when it tap on button. You can see my function that force to user to `Retry` for check again internet is connected or not. Otherwise it will dismiss alertview.?? Is there any way or have you any idea?

Comment: What part of this question looks like the `objective-c` tag should be involved?

Comment: Don't force the user. Users will hate you for it. Reachability is not a reliable indicator of network reachability. The only way to check that you can reach a URL is making a request and checking the result. Use notifications from Reachability to check whether something has changed so you can try again after a failed attempt.

Comment: BTW. Reachability reports that the device is connected to WiFi. It doesn't and cannot report that the device is connected to the Internet. It may also report that the device is connected only through mobile data, which again doesn't necessarily mean it's connected to the internet, but also means that downloads may be expensive.